# Получить значение Select, не val

Tags: jquery

Всем привет, есть такой select

```
<select name="s">
        <option value="1">Москва</option>
        <option value="2">Санкт-Петербург</option>
    </select>
```

если получают через `val()`, то получаю через id, а как получить название городов (Jquery)? Важно, id в value нужно оставить, для записи в БД

UPD получить выделенное значение, например если выбрали Москва, то что бы возвращал Москва, не 1

Comment: ничего не понял. нужно что, получить "Москва"? если выделен. или все названия нужно получить? Исправь вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что ты имеешь в виду.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исправил

Comment: Ну бери не val, а text

Comment: @АлексейШиманский через текст, он берет все значения select, Москва, санкт-петербург, а хотелось бы выделенного именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    console.log($("select option:selected").text());
    
    // или чуть правильнее:
    
    console.log($(this).find(":selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="s">
  <option value="1">Москва</option>
  <option value="2">Санкт-Петербург</option>
</select>
```